# DocumentBuilder parse File from absolute Path

Tags: java, jfilechooser, absolute-path

I have a basic Java-UI with an JFileChooser.

I try to parse the selected file with this Code:

```
Document document = builder.parse(getClass().getResourceAsStream(<SELECTED_PATH>));
```

Sadly i get this Output:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: InputStream cannot be null
at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:120)
at wordpress2myblog.WordpressBlog.importWP(WordpressBlog.java:59)
at wordpress2myblog.WPImportUI.jButton1MouseClicked(WPImportUI.java:165)
at wordpress2myblog.WPImportUI.access$000(WPImportUI.java:16)
at wordpress2myblog.WPImportUI$1.mouseClicked(WPImportUI.java:51)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(AWTEventMulticaster.java:253)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6385)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3275)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6147)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2083)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4744)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2141)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4572)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4619)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4289)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4210)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2127)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2489)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4572)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:710)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:82)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:669)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:667)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:98)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:683)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:681)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:680)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
at java.awt.Dialog$1.run(Dialog.java:1049)
at java.awt.Dialog$3.run(Dialog.java:1101)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1099)
at java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1591)
at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1543)
at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:843)
at java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Dialog.java:984)
at wordpress2myblog.WPImportUI$3.run(WPImportUI.java:222)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:708)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:82)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:669)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:667)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:678)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

If i try to parse a file with an hardcoded relative path the code works fine. but with the path getting from the file chooser these error kills my program.

Comment: Absolute path in the classpath or the filesystem? `getClass().getResourceAsStream` is for searching in the classpath.

Comment: Why don't you use a FileInputStream if you are using JFileChooser you don't select Files inside your jar so a FileInputStream would be the better approach?

Comment: As mentioned in the Answer below i used FileInputStream and it works now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the method getSelectedFile() from JFileChooser and create a InputStream with the returned File.

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
Document document = builder.parse(inputStream);
```